# Twitter bootstrap css down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, github, flask

ive been developing on Flask and the css i am currently using is from

```
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.css
```

but the site seems to be down, does anyone know where i can download this file

thanks

Comment: That url is working fine for me.

Comment: try http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: sorry wrong link, this is the one http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.css

Answer (score 1):

The link provided by tbicr is in the wrong mime-type (text/plain) so the css will not load in flask.

This link works better:

```
http://bootstrapdocs.com/v1.4.0/bootstrap.css
```

and seems pretty permanent - at least for trying out legacy code before puting in the effort to update bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap hosted on github, so all sources you can found in github. See `1.4.0` tag: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v1.4.0/bootstrap.css ([raw](https://raw.github.com/twbs/bootstrap/v1.4.0/bootstrap.css)).

But if you want just add it to your public site without modifications better use CDN (thanks **@Bass Jobsen**).